# Vectorized Partial Derivative of Multivariate Function in Python

Tags: python, numpy, vector, scipy, derivative

There was a phenomenal answer posted by alko for computing a partial derivative of a multivariate function numerically in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20708038/scipy-misc-derivative-for-mutiple-argument-function).

I have a follow-up question now about enhancing this function to accept an array of input values. I have some code where I'm looping through a big long list of n-dimensional points, calculating the partial derivatives with respect to each variable, and this becomes quite computationally expensive.

It's easy enough to vectorize the function in question with `np.vectorize`, but it causes issues with the `partial_derivative` wrapper:

```
from scipy.misc import derivative
import numpy as np

def foo(x, y):
    return(x**2 + y**3)

def partial_derivative(func, var=0, point=[]):
    args = point[:]
    def wraps(x):
        args[var] = x
        return func(*args)
    return derivative(wraps, point[var], dx=1e-6)

vfoo = np.vectorize(foo)

>>>foo(3,1)
>>>10
>>>vfoo([3,3], [1,1])
>>>array([10,10])

>>>partial_derivative(foo,0,[3,1])
>>>6.0
>>>partial_derivative(vfoo,0,[[3,3], [1,1]])
>>>TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "float") to list
```

The last line should ideally return `[6.0, 6.0]`. In this case the two arrays supplied to the vectorized function `vfoo` are essentially zipped up pairwise, so `([3,3], [1,1])` gets transformed into two points, `[3,1]` and `[3,1]`. This seems to get mangled when it gets passed to the function `wraps`. The point that it ends up passing to the function `derivative` is `[3,3]`. In addition, there's obviously the `TypeError` thrown up.

Does anyone have any recommendations or suggestions? Has anyone ever had a need to do something similar?

### Edit

Sometimes I think posting on SO is just what it takes to break a mental block. I think I've got it working for anyone who might be interested:

```
vfoo = np.vectorize(foo)

foo(3,1)
X = np.array([3,3])
Y = np.array([1,1])
vfoo(X, Y)
partial_derivative(foo,0,[3,1])
partial_derivative(vfoo,0,[X, Y])
```

And the last line now returns `array([ 6.,  6.])`

Comment: Bear in mind that `np.vectorize` is not actually any faster than doing the same thing using a normal Python `for` loop - it's just syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 0):

I have a small problem with args[var] = x : this might forever change args[var] , and all values have been passed by reference however small your change is. So you might not get the exact answer you are looking for. Here is an example:

```
In[67]: a = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
In[68]: b = a[:]
In[69]: b[0,0]=42
In[70]: a
Out[70]: 
array([[42,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8]])
```

you need to fix it by e.g.:

```
def wraps(x):
    tmp = args[var]
    args[var] = x
    ret= func(*args)
    args[var] = tmp
    return ret
```

Also, you can use [numdifftools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Numdifftools). They seem to know what they are doing. This will do all the partial derivatives:

```
import numpy as np
import numdifftools as nd

def partial_function(f___,input,pos,value):
    tmp  = input[pos]
    input[pos] = value
    ret = f___(*input)
    input[pos] = tmp
    return ret

def partial_derivative(f,input):
    ret = np.empty(len(input))
    for i in range(len(input)):
        fg = lambda x:partial_function(f,input,i,x)
        ret[i] = nd.Derivative(fg)(input[i])
    return ret
if __name__ == "__main__":
    f     = lambda x,y: x*x*x+y*y
    input = np.array([1.0,1.0])
    print ('partial_derivative of f() at: '+str(input))
    print (partial_derivative(f,input))
```

Finally: if you want your function to take an array of the parameters, e.g.:

```
f     = lambda x: x[0]*x[0]*x[0]+x[1]*x[1]
```

then replace the respective line with (removed the  '*')

```
ret = f___(input)
```