# Higher-order multivariate derivatives

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scientific-computing

**Is there a packaged way to compute higher-order multivariate derivatives (using finite differences, not symbolic calculations) in Python?**

For example, if `f` computes the function cos(x)*y from R^2 to R, i.e., `f` takes numpy arrays of shape `2` and returns floats (or arrays of shape `()`), is there a function `partial` such that `partial([2,1])(f)` computes the function (d^2/dx^2)(d/dy)f = -cos(x)*1 from R^2 to R, e.g.

```
np.isclose(partial([2,1])(f)(0),1.0)
```

There is a host of finite difference tools in the default libraries (so much for ''one way to do it''):

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.derivative.html
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.approx_fprime.html
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.misc.central_diff_weights.html
https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/statsmodels/tools/numdiff.py

However, none of them can handle both multivariate functions and higher-order derivatives, i.e., none of them can handle the job above.

(There is also https://pypi.org/project/numdifftools/ but it seems to fall just short of doing what I need. The authors haven't responded to my question.)

It's easy to write the tool myself. However, it seems to be surprisingly difficult to do so well, i.e., in an accurate and stable fashion. For example, a straightforward recursive implementation is unstable for mesh-widths smaller than `1e-3`, even for simple functions like the one above and for mixed derivatives of only second order.

PS: I am not asking for finite differences of an array (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html and https://github.com/maroba/findiff do that). I need to evaluate derivatives at arbitrary points without computing the values of the function on a full cartesian grid.

Answer (score 0):

There's `scipy.optimize._approx_derivative` which does it. This is however not a public function, so if you end up using it, you're on your own.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `scipy.optimize._numdiff.approx_derivative`?

Comment: How do you compute mixed/cross derivatives with that?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a wrapper and use the `scipy.misc.derivative` function.

For a simple x, y derivative, use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20708038/scipy-misc-derivative-for-multiple-argument-function) answer

For a vector derivative, you can define `g(t, (x, y), vector) = f((x,y) + t * vector)`, which yields `g'(0, args=((x,y), vector)) =` directional derivative in the chosen vector direction

```
from scipy.misc import derivative

f = lambda x: x[0] * np.cos(x[1])

def vector_derivative(f, x0, vector, delta=1):
    def wrapper(x, x0, vector):
        return f(np.asarray(x0) + x * np.asarray(vector))
    return derivative(wrapper, 0, args=(x0, vector), dx=delta)

vector_derivative(f, [1, np.pi/2], [0, 1], delta=0.01)
>> -0.9999833334166673
```

Comment: This can't handle mixed derivatives, can it?

Comment: The approach here is to transform the directional derivative (x, y, or generic direction) into a scalar function. You can always vectorize the function to work with different directions.

Comment: I'm assuming by mixed you mean cross derivatives. In that case you need to wrap it again (but it is easier to do it with the approach in the link provided, since this approach is aimed to being generic in terms of direction)